# HeatMap - dc.js and d3.js using JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, d3.js, dc.js

I can create a HeatMap using d3.js, dc.js and crossfilter, using data in a CSV file.

code:

```
var chart = dc.heatMap("#test");
d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, experiments) {
  var ndx    = crossfilter(experiments),
      runDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return [+d.Run, +d.Expt]; }),
      runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.Speed; });
  chart
    .width(45 * 20 + 80)
    .height(45 * 5 + 40)
    .dimension(runDim)
    .group(runGroup)
    .keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
    .valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
    .colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
    .title(function(d) {
        return "Run:   " + d.key[0] + "\n" +
               "Expt:  " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
               "Speed: " + (299000 + d.value) + " km/s";})
    .colors(["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"])
    .calculateColorDomain();
  chart.render();
});
```

but i want to do this same thing using JSON data, perhaps an array with some json data. This seems like a noob question but I was unable to find any example which uses JSON data for heatmap.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a JSON file then the code is going to be largely the same just replace `d3.csv` with `d3.json`.

If the data is already loaded in the browser then you can remove this function and just run:

```
var experiments = JSON.parse(json_object) //if json_object is still a string
var ndx = crossfilter(experiments)
```

and the rest of the code will be the same.